# Why is my Transaction Fact table generating a ORA-00920: invalid relational operator error?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am new to Oracle and have posted the code below, my dimension tables have all inserted correctly, it is just this fact table causing me this issue. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
INSERT INTO Transaction_Fact
(TermID, ResourceID, CampusID, SubjectID, MaxBooksOwned, Year, TotalBorrowed, FinesTotal) 
SELECT 1, '001', 'PK', 'TC001', 5, 2017, SUM(ResourceID * isReturned), 6
 FROM tbl_Resources1a
 INNER JOIN tbl_ResourceReturn1a
    ON tbl_Resources1a.ResourceID, tbl_ResourceReturn1a.ResourceID
    INNER JOIN tbl_Term
    ON tbl_ResourceReturn1a.TermID, tbl_Term1a.TermID
    WHERE Year >= TO_DATE('2017/01/01', 'yyyy/dd/mm')
    AND   Year <= TO_DATE('2018/01/31', 'yyyy/dd/mm')
    GROUP BY tbl_Resources1a.TermID
```

ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a comma isn't a valid relational operator (a.k.a [comparison condition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Comparison-Conditions.html#GUID-828576BF-E606-4EA6-B94B-BFF48B67F927)). Your `ON` clauses should (presumably) be testing for equality instead:

```
 INNER JOIN tbl_ResourceReturn1a
    ON tbl_Resources1a.ResourceID = tbl_ResourceReturn1a.ResourceID
 INNER JOIN tbl_Term
    ON tbl_ResourceReturn1a.TermID = tbl_Term1a.TermID
```